# How to keep text filed value on windows in flutter after resizing window

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, resize, textfield

i'm programming a desktop application for windows using Flutter SDK 3.7.12.
My problem is when the user enter any value in the textfiled and then resize the window the textfilled value removed as shown in the video V.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1flPqVlxTlN2q9ucPTKCTQwY5qmsFB61K/view?usp=sharing

here is my code:

```
                          Container(
                            width: 616.w,
                            height: 60,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16,left: 8),
                            child: TextField(
                              textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "رقم المعاملة",
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 112, 112, 112)
                                  ),
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.search,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 121, 175)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              controller: _controller,
                              onChanged: (String text){
                                _searchText = text;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
```

Comment: Where is your `_controller` created, it looks like every time your window is rebuilt, `_controller` is a new object.